# send a jpeg file from a microcontroller to a pc

Tags: serial-port, jpeg, microcontroller

I would like to send a jpeg file from a microcontroller to a pc. So I would like a program that would receive the jpeg file byte by byte. Then once it sees the end of the file it saves it to disk. Does anyone know if such a program exists or if not is there any code available that would do the job?

Thanks

Comment: it depends heavily on your platform and interfaces, if you already have a file system and files on the microcontroller then just use library calls already used for managing the file system...to manage the file...

Comment: I don't have any code and I think maybe some people have misunderstood what I am looking for. I have a JPEG file stored in the memory of a micro. I want to send each byte of the file out of the serial port to a pc. Then I want a program to capture each byte then save all bytes into a file with a .jpg extension. So I either need some code to do this or if there is a program that does something similar that I can modify.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the [XMODEM protocol](http://www.textfiles.com/programming/ymodem.txt) in your microcontroller firmware.  Then you could run a terminal application such as [TeraTerm](http://ttssh2.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en) on your PC to transfer the file.  You can probably search for and find example source code for an XMODEM implementation.